# How to use TEXCOORD0 in custom functions of Shader graphs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, fragment-shader, shader-graph

I have already implemented a code using normal shader and now I'm converting that to a shader graph. I used uv values to color certain area near the hit point using fragment shaders and how can I get the same results in shader graph custom functions ? Here is my code in normal shader.
How can I access this i.uv.x and i.uv.y in shader graphs?

```
fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
{
    fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
    if (abs(i.uv.x - _x) < 0.04 && abs(i.uv.y - _y) < 0.04)
    {
        col = _Color;
    }
    return col;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use UV Node with a combination of the Split Node.